Load Balancing Web Sockets with K8s/Istio
I have a service that is going to be handling 10s possibly up to 100s of thousands of web sockets simultaneously.
I am trying to figure out the best way to load balance this.
Say for example, I have 2 pods and each one reaches 10K connections, then my HPA scales up a new POD, now my connections are:
Pod1: 10K
Pod2: 10K
Pod3: 0
Load balancers will still continue to send new connections to pods 1 and 2. I would like them to start sending them to pod3 until it catches up.
Is this at all possible? What is the best strategy for something like this?

Have you checked this blog and this blog by daniele.

Istio by default will use least active requests with a catch. It chooses 2 hosts and takes the host with the least active requests. Check here and here.
Or you could try a custom envoy filter and write your own load balancer which can look at all hosts and find the host with least active requests.
